# Close JFrame with a "really close?" dialog

Tags: java, swing, jframe, oncloselistener

I have a JFrame and if I press the close button in the top right corner I invoke a JDialog and ask if the user really wants to close.

This is the ActionListener on the close Button in my main JFrame:

```
...
//close listener
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {//invoke "wirklich schließ3n" window if Alt+F4
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
                MainGuiWindow.this.saveSettings();
```

`CloseDialog cd = new CloseDialog(MainGuiWindow.this);
            if (cd.getResult()) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                //MainGuiWondow is "setVisible(false)" but still running | I don't know how to fix it
                MainGuiWindow.this.setVisible(true);//doesn't work
            }
        }
    });`

The JDialog has just two buttons (YES/NO) (after pressing any button i call dispose(); in the ActionListeners of the Buttons in the JDialog and after the dispose(); i return the answers:
yes returns true
no returns false

Can anybody tell me what to do in the else case of my Close ActionListener in my MainGuiWindow.
The CloseDialog is closed cause of the dispose(); but the main window is is setVisible(false); but still running

Comment: What do you want exactly to do in the else block ??

Comment: try using `frame.setDefaultOperationOnClose(WindowConstants.x)` -- if you're closing, use EXIT_ON_CLOSE for x, if not, use DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE.

Answer (score 1):

This my help you

You need to set default close operation on the JFrame to “do nothing”:

```
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

add a WindowListener for the frame.

```
jFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    handleClosing();
}
});
```

And [Refer Here](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/preventing-jframe-window-from-closing)